# Spring Boot : Cannot load driver class: org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have a simple Spring Boot application (generated through Spring Roo).

The database is configured as following :

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc\:hsqldb\:mem\:PetClinic
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.strategy=org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy
spring.messages.encoding=ISO-8859-1
spring.messages.fallback-to-system-locale=false
spring.thymeleaf.mode=html
```

Here are the how I declared the HSQLDB dependency  :

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
  <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

When I start the application, I get the error :

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load driver class: org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:392) ~[spring-core-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties.determineDriverClassName(DataSourceProperties.java:214) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
```

The Spring-boot-autoconfigure module tries to load the class with the `ClassUtils` utility class that loads the current context classes.

I wonder if this method works fine since I use a Tomcat container which is responsible to load the Maven dependencies ? 
Why even with the JAR in the libs directory Spring is not able to find it ?

Answer (score 9):

1. Remove `<scope>provided</scope>` from your `pom.xml`
2. Remove both `spring.datasource.driver-class-name` and `spring.datasource.url` properties from your application properties

Because:

- when `spring.datasource.url` is provided the driver class name is redundant as Spring Boot will automatically attempt to load the correct driver.
- since you want to use an embedded database you don't need to provide `spring.datasource.url` at all. Just need to have an embedded database JAR on the classpath (like HSQLDB)

Relevant docs snippet:

> Spring Boot can auto-configure embedded H2, HSQL and Derby databases.
>   You don’t need to provide any connection URLs, simply include a build
>   dependency to the embedded database that you want to use.

Please read the [Working with SQL databases](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-sql.html) section in of Spring Boot documentation. Everything I said is mentioned there, so you can get more detail.

Comment: I am using gradle and i  have implementation 'org.hsqldb:hsqldb:2.6.1' in my build.gradle and still facing this error

Answer (score 6):

I see the scope you gave is provided, `<scope>provided</scope>`, I don't think Tomcat provides the hsqldb.jar with it out of the box.

So try removing the provided scope.

Answer (score 1):

Try following dependency config in your pom.xml (change your version number accordingly or remove it)

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
   <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
   <classifier>jdk8</classifier>
   <version>2.6.1</version>        
</dependency>
```

For me adding that classifier line solved an issue.
Please see below recommendation in hsqldb repo.
https://sourceforge.net/p/hsqldb/bugs/1644/